# What is the difference between JSON , BSON and JSONB

Tags: json, jsonb, bson

I'm currently working on a project where I need to store and query data in a database, and I'm exploring different data formats to determine the most suitable option. Specifically, I'm considering JSON, BSON, JSONB, and possibly other formats. However, I'm unsure about the differences between these formats and their pros and cons for my use case.

Here are a few specific questions I have:

- What are the key differences between JSON, BSON, and JSONB?
- In terms of storage efficiency, which format offers the best compression and compactness?
- Which format is most performant for querying and retrieving data?
- Are there any limitations or considerations when using these formats in different database systems (e.g., MongoDB, PostgreSQL)?
- Are there any notable alternatives to JSON, BSON, and JSONB that I should consider for my project?

Comment: You can check this video which answers most of your questions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNpOl_klQP8